# ICMPv6 RA to make it as default gateway in the Network

Tags: ipv6

Hey guys if you are familiar with ICMPv6, i have a problem right now considering RA. I am trying to come up with a mitigation for last hop router attack, so i thought of how about sending a packet identical to the attack except the lifetime is 0. Will that work?

Also is it possible to have the computer consider me the router with just RA. Like my victim does not have any neighbor cache with myself?

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Let say i craft an RA Packet, I send that packet to multi cast every 5 seconds in a network without any router. Will the computers receiving the packet will getting there neighbor cache list change to me as a router

Comment: The neighbour cache is different from auto-configuration, but in short: yes, if you send an RA then others will see you as a router (RA=Router Advertisement after all), and if you advertise a lifetime > 0 then they will consider you a potential default gateway.

Comment: The solution for last-hop router attack is "IPv6 first hop security" (cisco terminology).  It lets you configure 'trusted' ports for RA's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that will work. Take a look at `ndpmon` which can do exactly what you describe.